# What is the advised way to make an empty array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

What is the best way to take an array in VB.NET which can either be Nothing or initialised and give it a length of zero?

The three options I can think of are:

```
ReDim oBytes(-1)

oBytes = New Byte(-1) {}

oBytes = New Byte() {}
```

The first example is what most of the developers in my company (we used to do VB 6) have always used. I personaly prefer the third example as it is the easiest to understand what is happening.

So what are the positives and negative to each approach (option 2 and 3 are very similar I know)?

---

**EDIT**
So does anyone know of a reason to avoid `ReDim` other that because it is a holdover from the VB days?

Not that I won't accept that as the answer if that is all anyone has!

Comment: Answer edited to provide additional justification for avoiding it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recommend: `oBytes = New Byte() {}`

You should try to avoid "classic VB-isms" like `Redim`, and other holdovers from the classic VB days. I would recommend the third option.

**Edit**

To provide some more information about why to avoid it, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28VS.71%29.aspx). While the page doesn't specifically advise against it, you can see that `Redim` suffers from shortcomings (and potential for confusion) that the other syntax does not.

1. `Redim` can only be used on *existing* arrays. Even so, it is semantically equivalent to declaring a `new` array. `Redim` releases the old array and creates a new one (so it isn't as if `Redim` has the ability to "tack on" or "chop off" elements). Additionally, it is destructive unless the `Preserve` keyword is used, even though there is no visual indication that an assignment is taking place.
2. Because `Redim` cannot create an array (but can only work on existing arrays), it can only be used within a procedure; at the class level you're forced to use the `New Byte() {}` method, leaving you with two visually distinct patterns for assigning new arrays, even though they're semantically identical.

Comment: Yes I agree, that's what has sparked this question, I tend to remove old VB code wherever I find it!

Comment: I couldn't agree more. "ReDim" and "New Byte(-1)" just look WRONG. To my eye it looks like it's saying ReDim oBytes(-1 to 0), which looks like it should give an array of two elements (which it will in Vb6). Please, please PLEASE can't the world just pretent there was no VB before VB.net? Please?

Comment: @Binary Worrier - 100% with you on this! It's the reason for most of the VB.NET usability issues!

Comment: @AdamRobinson awesome. I also fully agree. However, how do you make your empty array to grow? Using a `List` you convert to `Array` every time? That is the way to go when your arrays are immutable. The question is: you want it always? You cannot always know the size of an array before you perform a procedural task; and even if you could, performance would not improve in most cases due to your size pre-check. In other words: `push`, `pop`, `switch`, `unswitch` should be methods of the native class `Array`. How could have this possibly been backwards incompatible or affect performance?